# virtual fields in associated view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm having `$virtualFields` of users set in the model

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'fullname' => 'CONCAT(user.firstname, " ", user.lastname)',
    [...]
);
```

I want to access this field in a associated view, but I can load users data like firstname in the other view, but not the combined field fullname.

Do I have to add something into the controller to get this field.

Comment: You should have `User.field` not `user.field`. Models are CamelCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didnt read the last chapter of the book page here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields

Otherwise you would have seen, how do overcome the limitation of virtual fields here:

```
$this->virtualFields['fullname'] = $this->User->virtualFields['fullname'];
```